# Is there a way to asynchronously filter an IList?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, .net-3.5, repeater

Ok, so there has to be a way to do this... no? If not I'd love some ideas.

I have two repeaters and an image inside an update panel along with some AJAX dropdowns with link buttons to the left. I want to update the data inside the update panel as fast as possible as values are selected from the dropdowns.

What do you think would be the best way to update the data? The repeaters are populated by objects, so if I could just filter the objects by some properties I could end up with the correct data. No new data from the server is needed.

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: The best idea is to drop your use of the update panels and learn how to do some real DHTML with Ajax. Update panels are for bringing old websites up to date, I wouldn't design new apps with them because they are bandwidth hogs and hide too much from the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not easy to get just Data and data-bind the repeater on the client side. But, you might want to [check this out](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETRepeater.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap only the repeater you want to rebind with an update panel of its own.  The only viewstate transferred when doing this is the portion inside the update panel.  You may have to play around with the triggers and update mode of the panels to get everything to play nicely.

Another option is instead of using repeaters, serialize your objects into XML and then write a page method that returns an html string of your transformed data using xsl.  Then client side call your path method and update the DOM as appropriate.

A third option is to use use a service reference/page method to return JSON objects and update the DOM manually.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/ASPNETAJAXWebServicesTutorials.aspx

Good luck!  I have done all 3,

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already rendered to the screen, you can access the dom and manipulate the dom and hide/remove the ones you want.  I've done this with jquery, but the same should be possible with ASP.NET Ajax library.